# "Unable to locate package cinnamon" when trying to install cinnamon

Tags: desktop-environments, cinnamon

i want to install cinnamon on ubuntu 14.04, but i get an error "unable to locate package cinnamon"

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon

E: Unable to locate package cinnamon
```

yes, i did try `sudo apt-get update` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are receiving this error because there is no stable version of the cinnamon package in `ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev` for trusty - it's under development (now cinnamon nightlies are only available for trusty). If you want to install the development version of cinnamon (ie,nightlies) then run the below commands in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

Comment: Now it's just crashing so i will give up anyway :)